# provide a default location to look for a perl module only if not in default INC

Tags: perl

I have a module which I will need in most of my other modules.  ideally this module will in a directory pointed to by PERL5LIB.  Failing that I know the expected file structure of the modules, so I could theoretically find the desired module using a path relative to current module, to fall back on before failing.

The problem is that the standard use lib 'path' format looks at 'path' before it looks at the rest of @INC, such as those dir provided by PERL5LIB.  Is there a convenient syntax to specify paths to look at only after @INC has been searched, short of modifying @INC by pushing the variables to the back of the array?

Comment: hum... you shouldn't be touch `@INC` in a module.

Comment: Besides, if one of your modules was loaded, that means `@INC` already contains the path to your modules. Your request makes no sense. Which brings me back to my first comment. You shouldn't touch `@INC` in a module

Comment: @ikegami The modules are located in different directories.  The modules for may main program in one location. The umm..lets call them plugin modules that will be added regularly are located elsewhere, owing to how they are added.  I know the relative path from one to the other, but they are not, and will not, be in the same directory.  As to INC, I would prefer not to have to modify it at all, though both the INC and require do that if a path is provided to them, so clearly it's not that uncommon for people to add values to INC

Comment: What's that about not modifying `@INC`? The question asks how to modify the search path, `@INC`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a convenient syntax to specify paths to look at only after @INC has been searched,

No, there's no way to specify paths to search without including them in the list of paths to search (`@INC`).

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have perl version or perl architecture specific directories you want automatically included (the way `use lib` does), just do

```
BEGIN { push @INC, 'path' }
```

If you do have such directories, and you want to do exactly what `use lib` does only have the added directories come at the end, do:

```
BEGIN { push @INC, do { require lib; local @INC; 'lib'->import('path'); @INC } }
```